# how to run and control an excel instance from java

Tags: java, excel, com

My java application has a button which should open a user selected Excel file when clicked. On this file the user has to select a diagram. Finally they should click a button which triggers a process (macro, java method?) which changes the size of the diagram to values read from an object of the java application etc.

When searching on the internet I found things like COM bridges for java like [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/), but this seem to run on windows32 only; is there anything that works cross-plattform?

I would be very happy if somebody could help me to find a good approach, a fitting library or any other helpful hint, because I am a bit confused at the moment and don't know how to start at all ;)

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

edda

Comment: Why do you need a "cross-platform" COM Bridge? That is only available on Windows anyway.

Comment: Excel exists for Mac for example @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe the application is hosted on a non windows server, and communicates with a windows backend for this specific processing.

Comment: @jontro: isn't COM an "in-process" automation/communication? How could this possibly cross computer boundaries then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well you can use dcom (distributed com) across network. It's just a bridge. Automation is wrapped automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://j-interop.org/ . This can be used to call dcom applicaitons in a platform independent manner.